# Capture words on the right side of | (OR) in regex expression that are not in the left

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture words on the right side of this regex expression that are not captured on the left.

In the code below, the left side captures "17 inch" in this string: "this 235/45R17 is a 17 inch tyre"

```
(?<=([-.0-9]+(\s)(inches|inch)))|???????
```

However, anything I put in the right side, such as a simple +w is interfering with the left side

How can I tell the RegEx to capture any word, unless it is a digit followed by inch - in which case capture both 17 and inch?

Comment: And what's the connection with Elasticsearch? What are you trying to do with Elasticsearch and that regex?

Comment: Thanks, I am building a tokenizer to basically split a string in specific sections. Either on a simple space, or, the combination of a number and a space (5 inch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

```regex
((?:(?![0-9.-]+\s*inch(?:es)?).)+)|([0-9.-]+\s*inch(?:es)?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/fY9jU5/2

**Sample text**

```
this 235/45R17 is a 17 inch tyre
```

**Sample Matches**

- Capture group 1 will be the values that didn't match the `17 inch`
- Capture Group 2 will be the number of inches

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-20]  `this 235/45R17 is a `

MATCH 2
2.  [20-27] `17 inch`

MATCH 3
1.  [27-32] ` tyre`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-9.-]+                 any character of: '0' to '9', '.',
                                 '-' (1 or more times (matching the
                                 most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                                 (0 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        inch                     'inch'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                                 (matching the most amount
                                 possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          es                       'es'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )+                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9.-]+                 any character of: '0' to '9', '.', '-'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    inch                     'inch'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      es                       'es'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this definitely put me in the right path. The eventual string I got was: (?<=([-.0-9]+(\s)(inch)))|(?<!([-.0-9]))\s+(?!=(inch)) So the right side matches if the prefix and suffix are absent